# Verifying the validity of a structural induction proof

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, induction

Using structural induction, I need to prove that some set S possesses a property P. I understand the basic concept of structural induction, that is prove the basis is true and prove that for successive iterations of the recursive rule, the property P holds for new elements built from “smaller” elements that also have property P. However, I’m not sure if I’m doing this proof correctly:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any mistakes. I think the proof is correct as is.